# При наведении на меню двигаются элементы

Tags: html, css, menu, hover

```css
ul {
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 14px 10px 21px;
}

li:hover {
  background-color: #a5ffb9;
  border-radius: 150px;
  opacity: 0.9;
  color: black;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Здравствуйте. У вас просто меняется размер текста при наведении(font-size: 18px), из-за этого размер кнопки увеличивается, следовательно смещаются и соседние элементы.

Comment: сейчас здесь пойдут разные решения, вам нужно написать в каких границах можно менять CSS код, чтобы решить вашу задачу. Его можно полностью изменить? - например убрать inline-flex и прописать просто flex. Быстрое решение: ul {display: flex;} li{width: 33.33333333%;}. Если не подходит, пишите подробнее, что требуется.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для **ul** написал `display: flex; justify-content: space-between;` для **li** написал `flex-grow: 1; flex-basis: 0;` лишнее удалил, остальное немного оптимизировал.

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  list-style: none;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}

li {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 150px;
  font-size: 17px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 0;
  padding: 14px 10px 21px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  text-align: center;
}

li:hover {
  background-color: #a5ffb9;
  opacity: 0.9;
  color: black;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">კატეგორიები</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">კონტაქტი</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">ანგარიში</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```